# Generating records in a loop, they are out of order. Is this an Elixir or Postgres thing?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm generating some data for a test.

```
posts = for i <- 0..10 do
  :timer.sleep 100
  {:ok, post} = Post.changeset(%Post{},%{title: "Some Post #{i}"}) |> Repo.insert
  post.title
end |> Enum.reverse
all_posts = Repo.all(from p in Post, order_by: [desc: :inserted_at]) |> Enum.map(&(&1.title))
assert all_posts == posts
```

However this fails.

```
Assertion with == failed
     code: all_posts == posts
     lhs:  ["Some Post 10", "Some Post 1", "Some Post 2", "Some Post 3", "Some Post 4", "Some Post 0", "Some Post 6", "Some Post 7", "Some Post 8", "Some Post 9", "Some Post 5"]
     rhs:  ["Some Post 10", "Some Post 9", "Some Post 8", "Some Post 7", "Some Post 6", "Some Post 5", "Some Post 4", "Some Post 3", "Some Post 2", "Some Post 1", "Some Post 0"]
     stacktrace:
       test/models/post_test.exs:35: (test)
```

If I bump the sleep to 1000ms then it works, but it should really work without any sleep, right? Is this a Postgres or Elixir thing. Or am I not grasping how loops work in Elixir? These are generated and saved sequentially right?

EDIT: It looks like ecto inserts an erl time into the DB

```
INSERT INTO "posts" ("inserted_at", "updated_at", ...) 
VALUES ($1, $2, ...) 
RETURNING "id" [{{2016, 8, 15}, {7, 21, 50, 0}}, {{2016, 8, 15}, {7, 21, 50, 0}}, ...] query=1.2ms
```

So you'll only ever get precision to the second in this case. Is there any way around this, except sorting on inserted_at and id (that seems sloppy)

Comment: How long does one insert take in your database? Does it have some heavy triggers or checks or anything of the kind on this `posts` table?

Comment: @JustMichael There are 4 indexes, however all these records are identical, so they are affected the same. I think the issue is with Ecto. If Ecto.DateTime is inserting an erl timestamp, they are only accurate to the second. This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I checked if ecto timestamps have milliseconds and apparently they don't so you may be right.

Comment: @JustMichael Yeah, it seems like a major issue to me. I dont care so much about them being represented with millisecond accuracy after they're pulled out, but they should atleast orderable on the correct inserted_at time.

Comment: There is an option `usec` for the ecto timestamps, try to use it. Here's the info -> https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, you handsome devil. You can fix this by switching the :usec bool to true

`defmodule Post do
  schema "posts" do
    timestamps(usec: true)
  end
end`